# Captcha/Recaptcha for Mezzanine/Django forms

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

I am trying to add captcha to a contact form in [Mezzanine](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/) using [mezzanine-captcha](https://github.com/mjtorn/mezzanine-captcha).  However, I am getting a `no such table: captcha_captchastore` exception. Clearly, I am missing something in the database but I cannot work out what.  So,

1. What should I do to get the database updated so that it contains the right data?
2. How can I use [recaptcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha) with [mezzanine-captcha](https://github.com/mjtorn/mezzanine-captcha)?

Answer (score 1):

You probably haven't run syncdb: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#syncdb

Comment: Not familiar with it sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Question 2 - I installed django-recaptcha and did a little modification in the files, but you can follow these steps to use reCaptcha:

http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/recaptcha_with_django

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'll have to keep this in mind.  Due to hosting problems, I cannot test it.